# Pass returned value from a previous Python operator task to another in airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, etl, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am a new user to Apache Airflow. I am building a DAG like the following to schedule tasks:

```
def add():
    return 1 + 1

def multiply(a):
    return a * 999
dag_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 2, 27),
    'email': ['me@myhome.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=3)}
with DAG(
    dag_id='dag',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 27),
    default_args=dag_args,
    schedule_interval='@once',
    end_date=None,) as dag:

    t1 = PythonOperator(task_id="t1",
                        python_callable=add,
                        dag=dag
                        )
    t2 = PythonOperator(task_id="t2",
                        python_callable=multiply,
                        dag=dag)
```

As you can see, `t2` is dependent on the result of `t1`.
I wonder that is there any way for me to pass the return result from `t1` directly to `t2`. I am using Apache Airflow 2.5.1 version and Python 3.9.

I did some research on `xcom`, and found that all results of Airflow tasks are stored there, which can be accessed via code
`task_instance = kwargs['t1'] task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='t1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DAG can be simplified using [taskflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html). It will handle the Xcom and simplify the code.

```
import pendulum

from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
)
def taskflow_api_etl():
    @task()
    def add():
        return 1+1
    
    @task()
    def multiply(a: int):

        return a * 99

    order_data = add()
    multiply(order_data) # multiply uses the Xcom genreated by add()


etl_dag = taskflow_api_etl()
```

This code will generate the DAG:

[image]

When executing, `add()` task will generate Xcom with value 2:

[image]

The downstream multiply will read the xcom and do 2*99:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Although, I am curious that if I can replace all dags using ```taskflow_API```? Also, do you know how to pass returned value from XCom without using ```taskflow_API```?

Comment: Taskflow is the recommended way since its simpler, cleaner and with less code lines. The docs are very detailed on this topic. Specifically for your question: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#adding-dependencies-between-decorated-and-traditional-tasks